# Method to make UIGestureRecognizer fail after being recognized?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a question that might seem basic but can't figure it out.

Basic question is:  how do I programmatically put a gesturerecognizer into fail state from handler, while it's in UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan or UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged?

More detailed explanation: I have a long press gesture recognizer for UIView inside a UIScrollView.  I have made

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

because else I can't get scroll view to scroll once user puts their finger down at the view.  It's basic touch like safari, where you hold finger down on a link, which highlights the link, but scroll up or down - then link is unhighlighted and scrollview moves.

I can get this mostly working right now since both gestures are being recognized, but it would be better if I can detect movement in longpress gesturerecognizer's StateChanged, and if it's more than 20 pixels or so, just programmatically make longpress fail.

Is this possible to do?  Or am I digging at a wrong spot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another question that I found right after I posted the question..

Here's what I do in the gesture recognizer handler now:

```
else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    CGPoint newTouchPoint = [sender locationInView:[self superview]];

    CGFloat dx = newTouchPoint.x - initTouchPoint.x;
    CGFloat dy = newTouchPoint.y - initTouchPoint.y;
    if (sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) > 25.0) {
        sender.enabled = NO;
        sender.enabled = YES;
    }
}
```

So if finger moves more than 25 pixels in any direction, setting enabled property to NO will make the recognizer fail.  So this will accomplish what I want!

Comment: By setting sender.enabled to YES right after setting it to NO, are you actually doing anything? Setting it to NO seems to do nothing here. Did you mean to place sender.enabled to YES before the IF statement?

Answer (score 4):

If it is a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, just set its `allowableMovement` property.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [your recognizer];
recognizer.allowableMovement = 25.0f;
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation you can subclass you gesture recogniser:

In YourPanGestureRecognizer.m:

```
#import "YourPanGestureRecognizer.h"

@implementation YourPanGestureRecognizer

- (void) cancelGesture {
    self.state=UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled;
}

@end
```

In YourPanGestureRecognizer.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@interface NPPanGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer

- (void) cancelGesture;

@end
```

Now you can call if from anywhere

```
YourPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[YourPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panMoved:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
[...]
-(void) panMoved:(YourPanGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    [sender cancelGesture]; // This will be called twice
}
```

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer?language=objc